# Can someone be under the Cruciatus Curse and Imperius Curse at the same time?

Tags: harry-potter, spells, unforgivable-curse

Can someone be in severe pain under the Cruciatus Curse, and then have someone else come and successfully use the Imperius Curse on them at the same time? Or can they at least be under the Imperius Curse shortly after suffering from the Cruciatus Curse?

I honestly don't remember if someone can be affected by two spells at the same time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Crucio and Imperio can certainly be cast shortly after each other.

When the Dark Lord is resurrected in the graveyard, he uses Crucio on Harry, then very soon after that uses Imperio.

> “A little break,’ said Voldemort, the slit-like nostrils dilating with excitement, ‘a little pause … that hurt, didn’t it, Harry? You don’t want me to do that again, do you?’
>
> Harry didn’t answer. He was going to die like Cedric, those pitiless red eyes were telling him so … he was going to die, and there was nothing he could do about it … but he wasn’t going to play along. He wasn’t going to obey Voldemort … he wasn’t going to beg …
>
> ‘I asked you whether you want me to do that again?’ said Voldemort softly. ‘Answer me! Imperio!” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter (Priori Incantatem)*</sup></sub>

The blissful sensation of Imperio is shown to counteract the aftereffect of Crucio. When the Dark Lord cast it on Harry, he no longer felt the aches Crucio left him with, but once Harry fought it off, he felt them again.

> “And these words burst from Harry’s mouth; they echoed through the graveyard, and the dream state was lifted as suddenly as though cold water had been thrown over him – back rushed the aches that the Cruciatus Curse had left all over his body – back rushed the realisation of where he was, and what he was facing …
>
> ‘You won’t?’ said Voldemort quietly, and the Death Eaters were not laughing now. ‘You won’t say “no”? Harry, obedience is a virtue I need to teach you before you die … perhaps another little dose of pain?” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter (Priori Incantatem)*</sup></sub>

It’s clear from this the relief Harry felt was a direct result of the Imperius Curse cast on him, showing it can counteract at least the aftereffect of the Cruciatus Curse.

## It’s then likely that if Crucio is cast first, Imperio will stop the pain.

It’s never shown what would happen if the Imperius Curse is cast on someone who’s feeling the full effects of the Cruciatus Curse, but it’s possible, from what we see in the graveyard, that it’ll instantly stop the pain and replace it with the blissful feeling.

## However, it’s unclear if an Imperiused wizard could feel Crucio.

We don’t see any situation where someone under the Imperius Curse is subjected to the Cruciatus Curse. It’s unclear whether being under the Imperius Curse would make them incapable of feeling it, the pain would break the Imperius, or they would feel the Crucio but remain under the Imperius Curse. There’s also no comparable situation in the books that could give us information to theorize logically what would be most probable.

Comment: Did you by any chance experiment on the Longbottoms to find out this? :P

Comment: @marcellothearcane Yes, I did! ;) It was fun! :P

Comment: @Miss Bella I laughed out loud at your 'Yes, I did! ;) It was fun! :P' Thanks for that (humour is always welcome and fortunately find it everywhere but it's very welcome lately as you know). And here too I knew it was your answer. I like your analysis too. Your last point is a thought I had. I certainly would love to know the answer to that but probably at best we have speculation. The only thing I can say here is that it's possible that it would depend on the skill of the caster and how much - how to say it? - force they put into each of the spells.

Answer (score 3):

To my recollection, there isn't any 'canon' on this question [i.e no one in the books tried this].  However, a little common sense suggests that the answer is 'no'.  The Imperius curse clouds the mind, and normally it takes great force of will to clear one's own mind - but I'll bet nothing clears a mind faster than severe pain.  Conversely, someone already in severe pain probably can't muster enough bodily self-control to respond to Imperius'ed commands.